# How to delete the text in a file except the words I needed using VIM

Tags: vim

I have an XML file like this:

```
<text>
<A>12</A>
<B>13</B>
</text>

<text>
<A>14</A>
<B>15</B>
</text>
```

Now I want delete all the text in the file except the words in tag A.
That is, the file should contain:

```
12
14
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two commands (on one line if you like)

```
:g!/.*<A>[^<]*<\/A>.*/d
:%s/<A>\([^<]*\)<\/A>/\1/g
```

one line: (separate commands with a vertical bar `|`)

```
:g!/.*<A>[^<]*<\/A>.*/d | :%s/<A>\([^<]*\)<\/A>/\1/g
```

This will remove the blank lines...

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/^.\{-}\(<A>\(.*\)<\/A>\)\?.*$/\2/g
```

That assumes you have the same magic mode as me of course ;)  It doesn't remove the blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/\_.\{-}<A>\([^<]*\)<\/A>\_.\{-}>$/\1\r/
```

Gets everything but the final /text tag in one fell swoop :-) Fun stuff!!